# Video access with android AdvancedWebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Is there a way to give my android app camera access permission with [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView)?

It is possible with native webview, but the native do not allow file upload through < input type="file" >, so now I have the file upload working, but no camera.

Main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        mWebView.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

The

```
 mWebView.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
```

line gives the location permission just fine, is there something like that for the video?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manage to make it work!
Once you have your camera capture working in webbrowser, to grant the camera permission:

```
public void iniciaWebView(){

mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.setListener(this, this);
mWebView.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
mWebView.addHttpHeader("X-Requested-With", appNomeLogs);

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
        Log.i(appNomeLogs, "|> onPermissionRequest");

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(appNomeLogs, "|> onPermissionRequest run");
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }// run
        });// MainActivity

    }// onPermissionRequest
});// setWebChromeClient

mWebView.loadUrl(url);

}// iniciaWebView
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
```

Only tested in android 5 so far.

Comment: I was missing the permissions and after adding them it is working :)

Comment: 'grant' needs Api21 and more .any way to use in API15?

Comment: @Moises <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" /> this Permission is only granted to system apps

Comment: This is a good answer, but Android disagrees. See the documentation:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest
You need to grant access for each permission requested in accordance with the permissions of your application. You will have ANR if it happens that a certain WEB page of the server through HTML code requests access to resources that are not set in the Manifest file. You also know that the permissions from your Manifesto file must be approved in advance.

Comment: keep in mind that this is a 6 year old answer