# Click on website not working in WebView Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Hello I am trying to add this website (https://19.avchats.net/) into webView of android But the problem is Website have some buttons in it and one of them is used to join conference call. it need the Microphone permission to join. when we click on microphone icon in website it ask for microphone permission in website and if your allow it it join conference call. but the issue is when i add it into webview in android. the button who need microphone permission is not working other buttons are working. that button who need permission does not ask any permission. i have tried to give Audio permission manually to the app as well. but still not working. Please see the code i write:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            configureWebView();
        }
```

webview function

```
    private void configureWebView() {

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    // Set other WebView settings as needed
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); // Allow autoplay of media
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort (true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode (true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode (WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearFormData();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Log.d("TAG", "onReceivedError: "+error.toString());
        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://19.avchats.net/");
}
```

Website is working fine in mobile and in pc and in webview only the issue is with permission

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484438/8644685) is similar to your problem. Try to do it